# Where is WcfSvcHost.exe?

Tags: .net, wcf, host

I have Visual Studio 2019. I added the component of WCF (It doesn't come
by default).
I created a solution and added WCF service library.
This is a class library.

I understand that when I run the program, this class library will be
hosted by an executable file which is called WcfServiceHostSvcHost.exe.

l'm looking for the **location** of this file.
Tried in my computer, tried by google. No results.

Does someone know where is this file?

Comment: FWIW, on my box it's here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`.

Comment: Hi @500-InternalServerError  Thank you! you directed me around the right place:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE.   Of some reason, Windows explorer doesn't find this file (Even that now I search in this specific folder). It only finds WcfSvcHost.exe.config.   (although I see this folder contains also WcfSvcHost.exe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE

Of course the path can be different according to your IDE version.

Thanks for  '@500 - Internal Server Error' comment which helped me find it !